# Libgdx - How can I run 2 threads simutaniously

Tags: java, multithreading, libgdx

I want to essentially generate some files while I play the loading screen.

I tried to use Thread but it doesn't seem to work. It runs my thread first and finishes the thread before libgdx runs its render().

This is how my code works:
In my GameScreen Class:

```
private GenerateMap generateMap;
private Thread generate;
```

In my gameScreen():

```
    this.game =  game;

    MapChars.setDimensions(100, 100);

    generateMap = new GenerateMap(10);
    generate = new Thread(generateMap);
    generate.start();

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(240, 400);
    camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth/2, camera.viewportHeight/2, 0);
    camera.update();

    sideCam = new OrthographicCamera();
    sideCam.setToOrtho(true, camera.viewportWidth, camera.viewportHeight);
    sideCam.update();

    shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
```

and in my render()

```
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    size += delta;
    if(size >= 5)
        size = 0;

    if(!generateMap.isComplete()) {
        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(sideCam.combined);

        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);
        shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        shapeRenderer.circle(50, 50, 10*size);
        shapeRenderer.end();
    }
```

Is there a way to render and thread a t the same time?

EDIT:

This is how my GenerateMap Class works:

```
private void generate() {
    complete = false;
    // Do The file Generation...
    complete = true;

}

public boolean isComplete() {
    return complete;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    generate();

}
```

Comment: This should work fine.  Are you really sure they're not interleaving, or does it just look like they're not interleaving?  (Add some logging?)  Does your "isComplete()" method block on a lock?  What device are you running on?  (It could be that your generate map thread is starving the render thread.)

Comment: I would like to see, where and how you are starting the thread.

Comment: @Quallenmann I have updated my section to show the full declaration

Comment: @P.T. I have edited to show the generateMap Class

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I realized how stupid my question was.

I found that it only took about 0.03s for my thread to exit. 
So it looked as if nothing had happened.

When I extended the period to about 10s the thread worked properly !